# Xdebug from Docker suddenly stopped working in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I have used this for a long time without any issue, it was still working yesterday. I don't know what happened, maybe a silent update of PhpStorm or whatever - but it stopped working.

I checked with a local script, Xdebug still activates. I also used PhpStorm validation - no problem :

[image]

Now, when I load a page of the project, after activating the bookmarklet, it doesn't trigger anything. Also, I used to be able to launch scripts from the command line inside docker this way :

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=localhost"
php -dxdebug.remote_enable=On -dxdebug.remote_autostart=On -dxdebug.remote_connect_back=On -dxdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebremote_host=localhost myscript.php
```

I tried checking all debug relevant stuff in config :

[image]

Nothing goes. I'm pretty stuck here. Thanks ahead for any help.

PhpStorm Version - 2020.3

Comment: What's your PhpStorm version?

Comment: PhpStorm 2020.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xdebug 2.2.5
> PhpStorm 2020.3

That's an issue in PhpStorm 2020.3. It is already fixed ([WI-57282](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-57282)) for next minor 2020.3.1 version.

As I understand you are using some old PHP version (5.6 or alike) and cannot upgrade it to use newer PHP/latest Xdebug.

For the moment you either have to rollback to 2020.2.4 or wait for 2020.3.1 release ([2020.3.1 Preview build](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/12/phpstorm-2020-3-1-preview/) is already available; final version should be released at some point later this month).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it.