# PhpStorm receives incoming xdebug connections, but does nothing on them

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, ssh-tunnel

I am running `PhpStorm` on one machine and I am running `php-fpm` on another. I have a ssh tunnel between them.

I have a proofs of the following statements:

1. `ssh` tunnel is configured correctly and works (I am using `nc` and `nc -l` to test it).
2. `xdebug` is configured correctly and works (I am using `nc -l` to receive it's connections and also I can use another IDE (vscode) successfully)
3. `phpstorm` is receiving incoming connections

My site has constantly refreshing page and on my tunnel console I see constant messages

```
connect_to localhost port 9001: failed
```

Which proves, that `xdebug` is trying to connect to `IDE` on each refresh but failing.

Then I am pressing

[image]

`Start listening for PHP Debug Connections` button and these messages disappear.

This means that `ssh` was now able to connect to `IDE`.

But the problem is nothing else happens. No any breakpoint triggers, no any dialog appears to provide mappings, nothing.

What else can be checked to fix this?

---

Php version is: 5.6.33-0+deb8u1
Xdebug version is: 2.2.5
Phpstorm version is: 2020.3

---

The following appears in `xdebug` log:

```
Log opened at 2020-12-22 12:14:17
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9001.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///settings/html/load_menu.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="13307" idekey="1"><engine version="2.2.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2014 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>


<!**************** MY REMARK ********************!>


-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2020-12-22 12:14:17
```

Note `my remark` place. If I receive connections with `nc -l 9001` it waits in this place until I drop connection with `Ctrl-C`.

If I receive connection with `PhpStorm` or if I don't receive it, it passes this place immediately.

This means that `phpstorm` receives incoming connection and the drops it immediately. Why?

---

If I receive connections with `vscode`, a lot of messages like

```
<- breakpoint_list -i 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="1"></response>
```

appears in `my remark` place

Comment: *"Which proves, that php-fpm is trying to connect to IDE on each refresh but failing."* php-fpm is NOT trying to connect anywhere. If anything: it's Xdebug that tries to connect.

Comment: 1) Please enable Xdebug log, try to debug again and share the log -- it will tell what the response is. 2) What's your PhpStorm version exactly? 3) What's your PHP and most importantly Xdebug version?

Comment: @LazyOne I can't enable xdebug logging yet, it is separate problem

Comment: OK. What about #2 and #3?

Comment: For PHP Debug logs from PhpStorm side (after you get answer for the prev comment, not needed for now): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collecting-logs

Comment: @LazyOne I have fixed logs, it was permissions issue. I posted logs above. And Php version is: 5.6.33-0+deb8u1 
Xdebug version is: 2.2.5
Phpstorm version is: 2020.3

Comment: Thanks. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65322943/783119. Basically, for PhpStorm -- either use previous 2020.2.4 or [2020.3.1 Preview build](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/12/phpstorm-2020-3-1-preview/) for such old Xdebug version (there is a bug in 2020.3). Try that and update if debugging still does not work for you (new Xdebug log; what IDE shows etc)

Comment: @LazyOne preview build started to work immediately, thanks!

Comment: Please consider making an answer with your final solution. This will help other users in similar situation and having an accepted answer (which you can accept later) makes this question and solution more visible.

Answer (score 0):

No mistakes were found in setup. Turns out is was [a bug in PhpStorm 2020.3](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-57282) and switching to [Preview build](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/12/phpstorm-2020-3-1-preview/) helped instantly. Thanks to @LazyOne :)